# Firebase Authentication issue

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase authentication for my iOS project. I am facing problem of account override by google login case i.e if I logged in with email or facebook login then if I click on google login then from console account getting change in Google plus. 
I have disabled the multiple accounts with same email.
I am not getting this issue when I am using google plus login for first time.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior. Google authentication overrides other forms of authentication like Facebook or email/password if the same email is used. If this is not a behavior you want, go to [the Firebase website](https://firebase.google.com/) and leave feedback. In the meantime, here are some options:

- Deal with it as is. Users many not even care about it
- Turn on multiple accounts so users can sign in with either
- Keep a path in your database listing user emails for Facebook authentication, and then use a Cloud Function to scan it before authenticating a user on Google, preventing login if the email is found to belong to a Facebook account.